# Regular expression: match upto 3rd whitespace

Tags: regex

I have following line:

```
Data  5 in:out:40 Files
```

I want to match all the strings untill 3rd whitespace, So, in this case, I want to get back

```
Data  5 in:out:40
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Let's see some code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
^(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+)
```

Lets break this down:

```
^ # start from string beginning
( # match everything inside (begin)
  \S+     # match all non-whitespace(s)
  \s+     # whitespace(s)
  \d+     # match all non-whitespace(s)
  \s+     # whitespace(s)
  \S+     # match all non-whitespace(s)
) # match everything inside (end)
```

You can [test the regex in a debugger](https://regex101.com/r/L7GpQ2/1).

Comment: Why on earth is there a `\d` in a regex that has nothing at all to do with numbers?

Comment: Well I assume he has numbers there. Can't tell much without seeing more input examples. When he's more specific about his data one can easily modify the pattern.

Comment: Just replace the `[^\s]` and `\d` with `\S` and it'll do exactly what the OP described.

Comment: You can come up with your own answer then. OP can choose whichever suits him best.